# Rails4 migration default value is not storing into Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am working with Rails4 with mysql. I have generated some migrations and mentioned the default value for some fields but after creating row the default value is storing as "NULL" in the database.

```
    class CreateCities < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :cities do |t|
          t.string :name
          t.integer :region_id
          t.integer :country_id
          t.integer :status, :default => 0

          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

I am not getting why it's not storing!!! In controller part also did like this,

```
    def city_params
      params.require(:city).permit!
    end
```

Comment: So, what is it storing the value of status as? NULL? Can you post the parameters you see in rails server on terminal when you make request to server as well?

Comment: did you try adding null: false

Answer (score 0):

Try this in you controller

```
def city_params
  params.require(:city).permit(:name, :region_id, :country_id, :status)
end
```